# React Select re-focus after modal closes

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a problem with react-select.
On selecting option in the select input I need to open a modal.

After the modal closes i don't want the input to be refocused,
actual result is the the input gets focused after the modal get closed.

In this example i uses react-modal but not in my actual project.

Example code :

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-shannon-69n66?file=/src/App.js

Any way of fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the `select` dropdown using the `useRef` hook of react and in your `handleOnChange` method use that `reference` to close the dropdown. by calling it's function `ref.current.blur()`;

I've modified your code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-pine-jt1hv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Working but problem is that in other cases that I don't use the modal it will not stay focused after change. thanks.

Comment: Okay, then call `ref.current.blur()` whenever you close your Modal rather than calling it on opening the Modal.